# Использование BootstrapTooltip с SVG

Tags: bootstrap, svg

Применяю BootstrapTooltip к SVG-объектам:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
           <circle r="10" cx="15" cy="15" rx="5" ry="5" seat_id="812912" class="seat" seat_position="1" section_name="1" price="1650.0" title="" data-toggle="tooltip">      
           </circle>
           <circle r="10" cx="45" cy="15" rx="5" ry="5" seat_id="812912" class="seat" seat_position="2" section_name="2" price="1650.0" title="" data-toggle="tooltip">      
           </circle>
           <circle r="10" cx="75" cy="15" rx="5" ry="5" seat_id="812912" class="seat" seat_position="3" section_name="3" price="1650.0" title="" data-toggle="tooltip">      
           </circle>
</svg>


 $("circle").mouseover(function(){     
      var titleContent = "Ряд " + $(this).attr("section_name") + " Место " + $(this).attr("seat_position");
      $(this).attr("title", titleContent); 
      $(this).tooltip({title:titleContent, container:'body'});      
    });
```

Скрипт срабатывает, но не с первого раза. То есть нужно дважды навестись на объект. Подозреваю, это оттого, что я переназначаю значение title. Причем это происходит только при самом первом наведении на объект. Все последующие наведения обрабатываются корректно и тултип всплывает с первого раза.

Как исправить этот баг?

Демо: https://jsfiddle.net/ostapenko25/3war5ne9/

Comment: а зачем менять тултип при mouseover? почему нельзя сразу прописать необходимые тултипы?

Comment: не срабатывает, потому что вы при первом наведении его только подключаете.

Comment: не надо все это делать в `mouseover`. надо единожды настроить при старте. Если требуется динамический контент в тултипах, то следует привесить соответствующие события `show.bs.tooltip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы прикручиваете тултипы при первом наведении. То есть вы навели, прикрутили. Сами по себе они теперь не покажутся. Затем уводите мышь, и при следующем наведении событие срабатывает. В общем говоря для данной задачи можно либо единожды сформировать тултип для каждого места при старте страницы, как в примере них (либо вообще задать готовым атрибутом), либо динамически формировать в событии показа тултипа.

```js
$(function(){

   $(".seat").each(function(){
      let sn = $(this).attr('section_name');
      let s  = $(this).attr('seat_position');
            
      $(this).tooltip({
                     title: `ряд ${sn} место ${s}`,
                     container: 'body',      
                     placement: 'bottom',
                });
   });
});
```

```css
.seat { cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <circle r="10" cx="15" cy="15" rx="5" ry="5" seat_id="812912" class="seat" seat_position="1" section_name="1" price="1650.0" title="" data-toggle="tooltip"></circle>
   <circle r="10" cx="45" cy="15" rx="5" ry="5" seat_id="812912" class="seat" seat_position="2" section_name="2" price="1650.0" title="" data-toggle="tooltip">           </circle>
   <circle r="10" cx="75" cy="15" rx="5" ry="5" seat_id="812912" class="seat" seat_position="3" section_name="3" price="1650.0" title="" data-toggle="tooltip"></circle>
</svg>
```

зы: data-атрибуты никто не отменял.